# Google Assistant Increase/Lower Fan speed

Tags: actions-on-google

I am not managing to get the intent "lower the AC unit speed..." or "increase the AC unit speed" working. I am getting the answer AC unit does not support that functionality.

The traits action.devices.traits.FanSpeed works fine if calling explicitly the speed: "set the AC unit speed to low" ,"set the AC unit speed to medium" , "set the AC unit speed to high".

My understanding is that "ordered":True should do the trick, am I missing something ? Here under the attributes (Python):

```
"attributes": {    
    "availableFanSpeeds": {
        "speeds": [
            { "speed_name": "low", "speed_values": [{"speed_synonym": ["low", "speed 1", "min", "minimum"], "lang": "en" }] },
            { "speed_name": "medium", "speed_values": [{"speed_synonym": ["medium", "average", "speed 2"],"lang": "en" }] },
            { "speed_name": "high", "speed_values": [{"speed_synonym": "high","max", "maximum", "speed 3"],"lang": "en" }] }
        ],
        "ordered": True
     },
            "reversible": False,
```

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.